# How to Compute the Fixed Point on a DataFlow Lattice

Tags: lattices, data-flow-analysis

Wondering the general overview of how to compute the fixed point on a program's dataflow lattice.

A fixed point of a function $f(x)$ is one where the output of the function equals the input, so:

$$f(x) = x$$

Given $f$ is an order preserving (monotonic) function
$x ⊑ y \Rightarrow f(x) ⊑ f(y)$, in this [presentation](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-820-fundamentals-of-program-analysis-fall-2015/lecture-notes/MIT6_820F15_L17.pdf), they have $x_\bot$ be the least fixed point of $f: L \to L$, so $f(x_\bot) = x_\bot$, where $L$ is a program lattice. Then they say:

> Now, let $x_0 = \bot$ [the end of the lattice] and $x_i = f(x_{i−1})$
>
> - By induction, $x_i ⊑ x_\bot$.
> - Also, the chain $x_i$ is an ascending chain.
> - If $L$ has no infinite ascending chains, sooner or later $x_i = x_{i+1} = x_\bot$

I'm wondering what this means. What happens algorithmically (the high-level steps) when we are iterating toward a fixed point. In the presentation they say "*Do computation by simulating execution of program until reach fixed point*".

[This doc](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aldrich/courses/15-819O-13sp/resources/dataflow-frameworks.pdf) says "*In this situation [data flow], the mathematical function is the **flow function** [so $f$], and the fixed point is a tuple of the dataflow analysis values at each point in the program (up to and including the loop)*". They define *flow function* as a map from the dataflow info immediately before to after the *program point / instruction*.

So essentially, we divide the program into nodes or points where each point is an instruction/statement. We create a function showing the change of values from before and after each point (*in* and *out*, the flow function). We then iterate on the values somehow, that's where I'm unclear about. Wondering if we are iterating through the program points, calling $f$ for each point, or if we stay at one point and iterate on it with some sort of input until we reach a fixed point. Then wondering how that works. Not sure how the iteration works, or how $x_\bot$ works (if its part of some subset of the program points $L$ for each point (kind of like a neighborhood) or what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't compute the least fixpoint of a lattice; you compute the least fixpoint of a function $f$.  The standard method is to use a method called chaotic iteration, which is exactly the iterative algorithm described in your quote: set $x_0 := \bot$, $x_1 := f(x_0)$, $x_2 := f(x_1)$, etc., and keep iterating until you reach $i$ such that $x_i = x_{i+1}$; the resulting $x_i$ is the least fixpoint of $f$.

In some cases it is possible to speed this up for a particular function $f$, but don't worry about this at this stage.

It's possible to view the process above as in some sense simulating the execution of the program, but I find it likely that this viewpoint is going to lead to confusion, so I'm not sure I would recommend trying to understand it that way.  Iteratively evaluating $f$ is not the same as iterating through the program points of the program.

Talk about splitting the program up is largely irrelevant to your question about how to compute a least fixpoint.  There are two steps: convert the program to a function $f$; find the least fixpoint of $f$.  The business about dividing up the program is relevant to how you convert the program to $f$, but not relevant to how you compute the fixpoint of $f$ (at least, not at the basic level).